# Await getScript without chaining callbacks

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I have a setup function that I would like to use like this:

```
async function setup()       
{
    // Load the TF libs, then on complete - create the model.
    await loadTensorFlowLibraries();
    await createModel();
    await load();
    await train();
}
```

My first function imports some external scripts like this:

```
function loadTensorFlowLibraries() {

    $.when(
        $.getScript( "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.0.0/dist/tf.min.js" ),
        $.getScript( "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-vis@1.0.2/dist/tfjs-vis.umd.min.js" ),
        $.Deferred(function( deferred ){
            $( deferred.resolve );
        })
    ).done(function(){
        console.log("Scripts loaded");
    });
}
```

As this function runs asynchronously, `createModel()` is executed before `loadTensorFlowLibraries()` has completed and the script fails.

To fix this, I can pass a callback function to `loadTensorFlowLibraries` like so:

```
function loadTensorFlowLibraries(onComplete) {

    $.when(
        $.getScript( "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.0.0/dist/tf.min.js" ),
        $.getScript( "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-vis@1.0.2/dist/tfjs-vis.umd.min.js" ),
        $.getScript( "uploads/michaelryan/data.js"),
        $.Deferred(function( deferred ){
            $( deferred.resolve );
        })
    ).done(function(){
        console.log("Scripts loaded");
        onComplete();
    });
}
```

The problem here is that I would have to chain all my functions together like this, e.g.

```
function setup()       
{
    // Load the TF libs, then on complete - create the model.
    loadTensorFlowLibraries(createModel(load(train)));
}
```

Can anybody point me to how I could design the script like my first example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.when` returns a Promise-like object, so you can just `return` it from each of your sub-functions:

```
function loadTensorFlowLibraries() {
    return $.when(
        $.getScript( "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.0.0/dist/tf.min.js" ),
        $.getScript( "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-vis@1.0.2/dist/tfjs-vis.umd.min.js" )
    );
}
```

And then you can `await` it in your `setup` function, exactly like you're doing in your initial code block.